# How to read query string in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-2010, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am passing a query string to my ASP.NET Core MVC web simulator:

```
window.location.href = "https://localhost:7064/PaymentGateWayBillDesk/HitPaymentGateWay?queryString="+data;
```

How to read the query string when click on the button?

```cs
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> HitPaymentGateWay(string queryString)      
{
    String[] token = queryString.Split('|');

    if (token.Length == 22) 
    {
        merchantId = token[0].ToString();
        subscriberid = token[1].ToString();
        txnReferenceNo = token[2].ToString();
        bankReferenceNo = token[3].ToString();
        txnAmount = token[4].ToString();
        totalTxnAmount = txnAmount;
        bankId = token[5].ToString();
        bankMerchantId = token[6].ToString();
        itemCode = token[9].ToString();
        txnDate = token[13].ToString();
        authStatus = token[14].ToString();
        authStatusId = 1;
        settlementType = token[15].ToString();
        RU = token[21].ToString();
    }

    var vm = new PaymentDetailsModel() 
                 {
                     ReturnUrl = RU
                 };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but do you have the `[HttpGet]` attribute on that controller method?

Comment: Try to url encode the query string param using `encodeURIComponent(data)`

Comment: Following up on the comment @OctavianMărculescu had, is the class that the above method is implemented in inherit from `ControllerBase`?

Comment: [HttpGet] attribute  and inherited ControllerBase is there @OctavianMărculescu

Comment: Where do you get the error? Place a breakpoint on the first line of the method and check the `queryString` variable.

Comment: You can also try to decorate your parameter with the `FromQuery` attribute like this: `HitPaymentGateway([FromQuery] string queryString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "https://localhost:7064/PaymentGateWayBillDesk/HitPaymentGateWay?queryString=+data";
```

or:

```
window.location.href = "https://localhost:7064/PaymentGateWayBillDesk/HitPaymentGateWay?queryString="+"data";
```

result:

[image]

A demo you can refer to it:

Index view:

```
<button onclick="go2()">window.location.href</button>
<script>
    //function go2() { window.location.href = "https://localhost:7237/Home/HitPaymentGateWay?queryString=+data"; }
      function go2() { window.location.href = "https://localhost:7237/Home/HitPaymentGateWay?queryString="+"data"; }
</script>
```

result:

[image]